# Best way To download file on remote server

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-batch

I have To create a spring batch which have To connect on remote server ( nginx) and get list or files and download on local  server for treatment.
There is no API 
How To do that in the best way ? 
Ftp ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have an FTP server running, you could use [Apache Commons Net API](http://commons.apache.org/net) to download files as shown [here](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example). However, depending on your exact scenario, FTP might be [insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145008/what-are-the-risks-of-using-ftp).

As an alternative to FTP, WebDAV comes to mind, which is based on HTTP(S). I have used [sardine](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine) for uploading files to an apache httpd server from a Spring Batch client. I haven't set up WebDAV on nginx myself yet, but you can find quite detailed [instructions on the web](https://www.captainark.net/2016/03/26/webdav-with-nginx/).

Or if an sshd is running on the server, you could either use JSch to transfer the files via SFTP as described in this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-sftp) or use [`spring-integration-sftp`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.M4/reference/html/sftp.html) (which also uses JSch under the hood).

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually i have an SFTP connection so i can use your third solution

Comment: for parallel downloading, which one is the best choice ?